# reSIProcate on WinRT

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, sip

I'm getting stuck with building reSIProcate on WinRT. I got a syntax error in reTurnClient project( method getSocketDescriptor, in TurnTlsSocket.hxx)
This is error line code:

```
virtual unsigned int getSocketDescriptor() { return mSocket.lowest_layer().native(); }
```

This is error log:

> 5>e:\work\sigma\qilex-windows\resiprocate-resiprocate-1.10.1\return\client\TurnTlsSocket.hxx(23): error C2440: 'return': cannot convert from 'Windows::Networking::Sockets::StreamSocket ^' to 'unsigned int' (compiling source file TurnTlsSocket.cxx)
>   5>  e:\work\sigma\qilex-windows\resiprocate-resiprocate-1.10.1\return\client\TurnTlsSocket.hxx(23): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available, or (compiling source file TurnTlsSocket.cxx)
>   5>  e:\work\sigma\qilex-windows\resiprocate-resiprocate-1.10.1\return\client\TurnTlsSocket.hxx(23): note: There is no context in which this conversion is possible (compiling source file TurnTlsSocket.cxx)

I know It's type conflict error, but haven't got any clue to start fixing.

Comment: Can you post the line giving the error?

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT It's at line 23, file TurnTlsSocket.hxx : virtual unsigned int getSocketDescriptor() { return mSocket.lowest_layer().native(); }

Comment: I have no idea about logic and usage of this method. So that I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: So you have a link to the file?